# Why is gravity believed to have been as strong as the other fundamental forces at the beginning of the universe?

Tags: forces, gravity, big-bang

Why is gravity believed to have been as strong as the other fundamental forces at the beginning of the universe and what should be the cause of that possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy densities close to the very beginning of the universe were extremely high. There is a group of theories, called [Grand Unified Theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory), that hypothesise that at such extreme energy densities all four of the [fundamental interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction), including gravity, behaved symmetrically. However, this is still a hypothesis - the energy densities required are far beyond anything we can investigate directly, and there is no hard evidence that any of the various Grand Unified Theories are true. They are certainly not part of the Standard Model of particle physics.

So why do physicists even think that a Grand Unified Theory *might* be possible ? There are several reasons:

1. Electricity and magnetism were once thought of as separate forces, but we now know they are separate manifestations of a single force, which we call electromagnetism. We also know that at high energies the electromagnetic force and the weak force are unified into a single [electroweak interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction). Grand Unified Theories seek to extend this to the strong force and to gravity.
2. A Grand Unified Theory would explain some things which are not explained by the Standard Model, such as why electrons and protons have charges that are exactly the same magnitude.
3. A Grand Unified Theory is a highly symmetric theory. Physicists prefer theories that involve symmetry because they require fewer basic assumptions. An unsymmetric theory that said gravity is just really different from other forces would invite the question "but why should gravity be different ?".

Comment: The unification of the electric and magnetic force is based on a different mechanism than the unification of the weak and EM interaction.